# Question about airline routing with oceanic flightplans

Tags: flight-planning

so I looked up my recently flight from Incheon, South Korea to JFK on Flightaware (Korean Air 85 on Wednesday 8/23):

[image]

[Image source](https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/KAL85/history/20230823/1050Z/RKSI/KJFK)

The "route" under "Flight Data" is just 4348N/08224W IGN IGN1; however, my flight seems to take on a much more intricate route; on Skyvector, it looks like we went on airway Y697-G597 and Y51 between Korea and Japan, and then onto an oceanic routing that didn't really resemble the Pacific tracks, which usually are a lot more south than the route we took. Our route lead straight into northern Alaska. In contrast, this flight, also from Incheon to JFK, seems to include all of its waypoints and airways on Flightaware:
[image]

[Image source](https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/KAL81/history/20230827/0110Z/RKSI/KJFK)

This BA flight from Heathrow to JFK also seems to lack detail in its flightplan. The first waypoint listed is just offshore Canada; there are no waypoints in the UK that guide it toward the North Atlantic Track system:

[image]

[Image source](https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/BAW115/history/20230825/1345Z/EGLL/KJFK)

On US domestic flights, the flightplans on Flightaware seem sufficiently detailed, and the planes generally follow those routing. So my question is: on flights over the ocean, is it common for flight plans to include rather vague information on routing when filed initially (or could this just be an issue with Flightaware)? Would it then be up to ATC to issue an initial routing when the pilots pick up their IFR clearance? If so, I wonder why this would be the case, instead of the airlines' dispatchers just supplying their own routings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FlightAware pulls much of its information, including routing information, directly from the FAA—and possibly from other air navigation providers in other countries. The routing that is stored in the FAA's computer will be what is shown in FlightAware.

When the route does not have to be updated, the original route as filed/processed will be retained in the computer. Your KAL81 example shows this.

However, when a controller updates the route of an airborne aircraft, the route information prior to the update point is no longer necessary; the computer throws it away, retaining only the update point and the new downstream routing. This is what happened to the KAL85 flight that you were on.

Note that the update point for KAL85 is 43º48'N, 082º24'W. [Checking SkyVector](https://skyvector.com/?ll=43.80017561912385,-82.39965820185058&chart=304&zoom=3&fpl=%20RKSI%204348N08224W%20IGN%20IGN1%20KJFK) we see that this point is *just* within Cleveland Center airspace. But compare to the FlightAware track: Your flight did **not** pass so far west and south, just off the eastern edge of Michigan. Instead it entered the Lower 48 in upstate New York, well within Boston Center airspace. So I'm not sure exactly why a controller updated the route using that coordinate point... but they did, and that is why FlightAware doesn't show the entire route.

Comment: Nice answer! Is the FAA source of that routing info available to the public, or only to providers like FlightAware & such?

Comment: Aha, thank you so much! Yeah, I remember shortly before boarding, the first waypoint was POWAL, which is far into the ocean--so I guess only the routing at and after POWAL was updated before I looked up my flight on the website. And then during my flight, it was updated once more

Comment: @RalphJ You can look through [the SWIM registration process](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/technology/swim/products/get_connected) and see what the application form looks like. I imagine that it isn't available to Joe Q. Public, or at least the information would be heavily filtered.

Comment: @randomhead I think I have a new project to learn about... thank you!!!